# Sphinx query for "starts-with" condition

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am trying a query to search a table in which names start with a letter g.

```
"hospital @name ^g"
```

Is this right ? I am getting 0 results for it even after indexing the table with names and  all other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have min_prefix_len set to 1 for that index? Without this Sphinx treats "g" as a separate word and will match only those documents that start with one-letter word "g", for example "g anotherword".